# How to retrieve the largest number of items in multiple dictionaries

Tags: python, dictionary

There are multiple dictionaries as follows.

```
dicts = {'key': 'a'},
        {'key': 'b'},
        {'key': 'c'},
        {'key': 'a'},
        {'key': 'a'},
        {'key': 'd'},
        {'key': 'a'},
        {'key': 'c'},
        {'key': 'a'},
        {'key': 'a'},
        {'key': 'c'},
        {'key': 'd'},
        {'key': 'a'},
        {'key': 'a'},
        {'key': 'b'},
        {'key': 'b'},
        {'key': 'd'},
        {'key': 'b'},
        {'key': 'b'},
        {'key': 'd'},
        {'key': 'b'},
        {'key': 'b'},
        {'key': 'c'}
```

I want to do the following.
1)Exclude those whose key value is `a`.
2)Retrieve the most frequent value out of `a`.

I think that it can be handled easily with the for statement, but since there is a possibility that the number of dictionaries actually can be as many as tens of thousands, I would like to know the code that can be processed as soon as possible.

Comment: This isn't syntactically valid Python - did you mean for ```dicts``` to be a list?

Comment: Do all your dictionaries have the same key?

Comment: Ok, now, what is your problem? Did you tried something?

Comment: When you say `out of a`, you mean... excluding 'a'?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming `dicts` is a list or tuple:

```
from collections import Counter
ans = Counter(dic['key'] for dic in dicts if not dic['key'] == 'a').most_common(1)[0]
```

This will work regardless of whether `a` is, in fact, the most popular value. Results in

```
('b', 7)
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `dicts` is actually a `list` of `dicts`:

1/ Exclude those whose key value is 'a'

```
filtered = [d for d in dicts if d["key"] != 'a']
```

2/ Retrieve the most frequent value out of 'a'

(I assume you mean: the most frequent value once 1. has been applied)

```
from collections import Counter
c = Counter(d["key"] for d in dicts if d["key"] != 'a')
print c.most_common()[0]
```